# Error on using alert in Javascript (Property 'alert' of object is not a function)

Tags: javascript, jquery, alert, typeerror

I am just trying to use alert and put a string variable inside the alert and get an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Property 'alert' of object [Object Window] is not a function
```

My code is:

```
var shortenurl = msg.d;
alert(shortenurl);
```

I've checked the value and it has a string inside, not an object.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I had that error message due to an `alert()` blocked by my pop-up-blocker.

Comment: Wow man, thanks a lot... would have bever tought about that ;)

Answer (score 45):

Somewhere in your code you overrode `alert`. Check for `var alert = ...` or some other kind of declaration like that. Also check for `window.alert` declarations.

Comment: Possibly not `var` but simply `alert = "whatever";`.

Answer (score 6):

I'm adding this one as an addition to this.  In my case, when I had a similar problem, it turned out to not be my own code that was causing the problem but a poorly written extension that had been added to a client's browser.  Once it was disabled, the script error went away.

If you haven't overridden the method name in your own code anywhere, you may want to try disabling extensions to see if any of those is inadvertently interfering with your script.

Comment: Yeah that was my problem too. In Chrome, Ctrl+Shift+N to jump into an incognito window. Run a test in there.

Also, if this is the case, you'll notice that alert() fails on every site, not just what you're working on.

Comment: Yeah, i had a popup blocker, which was disabling alerts. I disabled that extension in chrome and now it works fine

Answer (score 4):

Check if you've got a Bootstrap .js declaration if required (after jQuery) i.e.

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding to Chris's answer... I had mistakenly overrode alert in my own function!

```
    //Don't do this:
    function alertOrConsole(node, alert){
        if(alert){
            alert(node);
        }else{
            console.log(node);
        }
    }
```

---

```
   //----------------------------
   //Fixed:
    function alertOrConsole(node, flag){
        if(flag){
            alert(node);
        }else{
            console.log(node);
        }
    }
```

Comment: This! Or as in my case, a state hook in React called alert: 
const [alert, setAlert] = usestate(null);

Comment: Brilliant! lol 

Answer (score 1):

One of the possible reasons could be that alert is used as variable - for example inside of function:

function MyFunction(v1,alert)
{
alert(v1); //will fail exactly with that message
}

Solution is not to use predefined words as variables.

Comment: helped this tip.

Answer (score 0):

**Mozilla says,**

```
The alert function is not actually a part of JavaScript itself.
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript

You can not see a function called alert here : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects