# TypeError: alert is not a function

Tags: javascript, web

```
if (name === "billy") {
  alert("Hi Billy");
}
```

> UncaughtType Error: alert is not a function at :2:2

Comment: Perhaps you have inadvertently overriden `alert` elsewhere in your code, due to something like `alert = "Hello World"`? Some pop-up blockers do this intentionally as a method of disabling alerts. Regardless, the code you've provided *does not recreate the issue*, therefore we can only blindly guess.

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/17833703/753237

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error on using alert in Javascript (Property 'alert' of object is not a function)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11334581/error-on-using-alert-in-javascript-property-alert-of-object-is-not-a-function)

Comment: I think @Tyler Roper is right, I had a similar error, after reading his comment, it turns out I am passing alert as props from another component, this was as a result of a bad naming convention though. but his comment saved me