# alert is not a function

Tags: javascript, alert

I am a very beginning  in javascript and these are my first lines in it
I am following a tutorial and I believe I did the same but even though I have this flag error, I saw the same questions but still don’t understand  the cause of the problem
[image]
my code

```
alert("hello");
```

the error

```
index.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: alert is not a function
at index.js:1
(anonymous) @   index.js:1
```

Comment: Please add the browser and the version. The snippet works for me in Chrome

Comment: @jonrsharpe they are running a [snippet](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/javascript/snippets/) in Chrome

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/11334581/3001761

Answer (score 0):

The `alert()` function is a JavaScript function in Web Browsers. You can not use it in a plain .js file that you execute locally; you *have* to run it in a web browser. FInd more information [here](https://webplatform.github.io/docs/tutorials/your_first_look_at_javascript/#:%7E:text=To%20execute%20JavaScript%20in%20a,element%20with%20a%20src%20attribute.) and [here](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-run-JavaScript-code).

Comment: They are running it in browser as [a snippet](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/javascript/snippets/)

Comment: Sorry mate, didn't see that because of the colourscheme. I thus assumed this was an IDE and didn't notice the other Developer's Console tabs. The snippet works for me too, so I am not sure what is happening. Maybe OP is experiencing an issue with the specific version of Chrome having a bug?

Answer (score -1):

There is one more possible reason: alert might be blocked by browser extensions (like ad blockers). Check window.alert in your console. If it's not a function, that might be the case.